# Embedding Excel Add-Ins with OpenXml

Tags: excel, office-js, openxml

My team is working on an Office 365 add-in for Excel, and as part of the project, we’re creating Excel documents through the GraphAPI with the end goal of having the add-in already setup for the document. We’re using the .NET OpenXml library to create the document before copying it through the GraphAPI.

We haven’t been able to find many resources for how to setup an add-in through OpenXml and have not been able to get anything working. The last thing we tried was copying the example we found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin/blob/379452948c9ff41f67cc3f2631e79977f672e45c/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin/OOXMLHelper.cs#L53), but we couldn’t get it working. Does anyone know how to setup add-ins using the OpenXml library?

Note: the add-in is already in the Office Add-Ins store, and we have information like the AppSource ID.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're actually about to publish a new sample around this scenario. The sample shows how to create an Excel document using OOXML, embed your add-in, and then upload the file to OneDrive. It also creates a Team chat that links to the file.

You can try out the sample here: [Open data from your web site in a spreadsheet in Microsoft Teams](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/davech-open-in-teams/Samples/excel-open-in-teams)

Or give us feedback on the PR: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/pull/197

To answer your question about how to embed the add-in, you need to create a web extension section. I've copied the relevant code here. Note this is the same code from the [Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin) sample you already looked at. We reused it for the new sample. You can change the CUSTOM MODIFICATION section to provide any custom properties you want to your add-in when it opens.

```cs
// Embeds the add-in into a file of the specified type.
private void EmbedAddin(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet)
{
   spreadsheet.DeletePart(spreadsheet.WebExTaskpanesPart);
   var webExTaskpanesPart = spreadsheet.AddWebExTaskpanesPart();
   CreateWebExTaskpanesPart(webExTaskpanesPart);
}

// Adds child parts and generates content of the specified part.
private void CreateWebExTaskpanesPart(WebExTaskpanesPart part)
{
   WebExtensionPart webExtensionPart1 = part.AddNewPart<WebExtensionPart>("rId1");
   GenerateWebExtensionPart1Content(webExtensionPart1);

   GeneratePartContent(part);
}

// Generates content of webExtensionPart1.
private void GenerateWebExtensionPart1Content(WebExtensionPart webExtensionPart1)
{
   // Add web extension containg Id for Script Lab add-in
   We.WebExtension webExtension1 = new We.WebExtension() { Id = "{635BF0CD-42CC-4174-B8D2-6D375C9A759E}" };
   webExtension1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("we", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11");

   // Add store information for Script Lab add-in
   We.WebExtensionStoreReference webExtensionStoreReference1 = new We.WebExtensionStoreReference() { Id = "wa104380862", Version = "1.1.0.0", Store = "en-US", StoreType = "OMEX" };
   We.WebExtensionReferenceList webExtensionReferenceList1 = new We.WebExtensionReferenceList();

   We.WebExtensionPropertyBag webExtensionPropertyBag1 = new We.WebExtensionPropertyBag();

   // Add the property that makes the taskpane visible.
   We.WebExtensionProperty webExtensionProperty1 = new We.WebExtensionProperty() { Name = "Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", Value = "true" };
   webExtensionPropertyBag1.Append(webExtensionProperty1);

   // CUSTOM MODIFICATION BEGIN
   // Add the property that specifies the snippet to import.
   string snippetToImportValue = string.Format("{{\"type\":\"gist\",\"id\":\"{0}\"}}", "{72189570-AE11-4207-9DEE-C8BDE4B83188}");
   We.WebExtensionProperty webExtensionProperty2 = new We.WebExtensionProperty() { Name = "SnippetToImport", Value = snippetToImportValue };
   webExtensionPropertyBag1.Append(webExtensionProperty2);
   // CUSTOM MODIFICATION END

   We.WebExtensionBindingList webExtensionBindingList1 = new We.WebExtensionBindingList();

   We.Snapshot snapshot1 = new We.Snapshot();
   snapshot1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

   webExtension1.Append(webExtensionStoreReference1);
   webExtension1.Append(webExtensionReferenceList1);
   webExtension1.Append(webExtensionPropertyBag1);
   webExtension1.Append(webExtensionBindingList1);
   webExtension1.Append(snapshot1);

   webExtensionPart1.WebExtension = webExtension1;
}

// Generates content of part.
private void GeneratePartContent(WebExTaskpanesPart part)
{
   Wetp.Taskpanes taskpanes1 = new Wetp.Taskpanes();
   taskpanes1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wetp", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/taskpanes/2010/11");

   Wetp.WebExtensionTaskpane webExtensionTaskpane1 = new Wetp.WebExtensionTaskpane() { DockState = "right", Visibility = true, Width = 350D, Row = (UInt32Value)4U };

   Wetp.WebExtensionPartReference webExtensionPartReference1 = new Wetp.WebExtensionPartReference() { Id = "rId1" };
   webExtensionPartReference1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

   webExtensionTaskpane1.Append(webExtensionPartReference1);

   taskpanes1.Append(webExtensionTaskpane1);

   part.Taskpanes = taskpanes1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @david! I played with OpenXML Productivity Tool, and it has been very helpful! I also dug into the code sample, and I have a few follow up questions (if you don’t mind): - Is the ID for the WebExtension the same as the ProductID from our manifest.xml? - I substituted our add-in information in GenerateWebExtensionPart1Content, but the add-in does not load. The add-in is accessible in the Store by ProductId, but it has not been published. Would this prevent the add-in from loading? Thank you again for your time!

Comment: I believe the Id can be any value. I tried changing it to a random GUID, and Script Lab still opens in the document. It's the WebExtensionStoreReference() parameters that must match your add-in. Like "wa104380862" as the Id for Script Lab (and also the product ID you can find Script Lab under if you search the Office store.)  As long as you can find your add-in in the store, I would think it should load in the document.